# Why this if statement doesn't execute properly?

Tags: java

I am using Netbeans to create a login system which then gets redirected to an Account page. However I'm stuck on this if statement and need help.

```
private void loginBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String password = passWord.getText();
    String username = userName.getText();

    if("red".equals(password) && ("safdari".equals(username))) {
        MembershipPage Account = new MembershipPage();
        Account.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "login is incorrect!");
    }
}
```

What's expected is for another JFrame to open up after I type in the login credentials "safdari" and "red". However, for some reason that's not the case and the else statement activates instead. I'm confused new to Java btw.

Comment: Try to debug your statements using breakpoints / the debugger so that you know the exact value of `password` and `username` at the time of entering the `else {` branch instead.

Comment: My money is on leading / trailing whitespace

Comment: whitespace? but it's java i thought whitespace and indentation doesn't really matter.

Comment: Whitespace in the `String`

Comment: Try `if("red".equals(password.trim()) && ("safdari".equals(username.trim())))`

Comment: Maybe your input hasn't the proper format. I am agree with the previous comment, some whitespace might be present in your input, or a capitalized letter.

Comment: i've tried the trim() method however nothing has worked - I am working with java swing - creating a gui and this is what my input looks like when im testing the code - https://gyazo.com/1df0532ce35e92b11116cc154a2d0907

Comment: can you try writing System.out.println() method on both your password and username and then see if they are exactly same as your expecting.

Comment: Can you please provide the code from where passWord and userName get its value. It may not be initialized correctly.

Comment: I tested your code on my machine and it is working fine. Nothing wrong. Maybe wrong with your input values.

Comment: Check your `Capslock` status and do `passWord.getText().trim();` and `userName.getText().trim();`

Comment: So guys thanks for your help, the problem with this was the fact that i was using the wrong variable names, - since i was using NetbeansIDE to create a GUI login form for a gym.